# Create dynamic items in list view using kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am working in a web application, which using Kendo UI. I required a dynamic box  view in list view. ie, there is a plus and minus button, so when user click on that button , new boxes should create and can add items to the selected box.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Created a single template, but I have no idea to add  this template dynamically to list view

Comment: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listview/editing

Comment: @GaloisGirl Thank you, but I am using viewmodels for binding, so how can I achieve this?

Comment: ViewModels shouldn't matter. If you want detailed help you need to include code.